# Unable to start service Intent act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I use gcm. When trying to register a device and receive an error: `Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) } U=0: not found`

```
regbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Registering device");
    // Retrive the sender ID from GCMIntentService.java
    // Sender ID will be registered into GCMRegistrar
    GCMRegistrar.register(TestActivity.this,
            GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);
  }
});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, what kind of phone do you have?

Comment: I forgot to write. I use the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCMRegistrar is no longer supported and should not be used. You do need ad device or emulator with Google Play services. Have a look at the [supported libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) that allow you to send FCM (previously GCM) messages to client devices.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a device with Google Play Services installed. In case you use an emultor, you will need one with Google APIs.
Make sure you prepare for this case, as there might be devices without play services, especially if you release somewhere else than Play Store.